# Apache Spark SQL NumberFormatException

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.2 for some data processing. I have created a schema using StructField.

```
val exampleSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("SerialNo",StringType,true),StructField("Date",DateType,true),StructField("Value",IntegerType,true)))

val exampleRowRDD = rawData.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0),repairDate(p(1)), p(2).toInt) )


val schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(exampleRowRDD, exampleSchema)

schemaRDD.registerTempTable("ExampleTable")
```

Now when I am running the query against the table, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line16.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
    at $line16.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
```

I know my data has null values, and I tried to treat the null values with Option, Some, None method, but then Spark SQL doesn't recognize the data type. So the bottom line is for my "Value" column all the values should be an integer but null can't be converted into the integer. 
What should I do? Working sample code example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which returns an `Option[Int]` instead of throwing a `NumberFormatException` using [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try) :

```
import scala.util.Try

def parseInt(s: String): Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption
```

Which you could use as :

```
val bad1 = ""
val bad2 = (Int.MaxValue + 1L).toString
val good = "5"

parseInt(bad1) // None
parseInt(bad2) // None
parseInt(good) // Some(5)
```

You will need to adapt you code to handle `Option[Int]` of course.

- You could work with `Option[Int]` in the rest of your code
- or supply a default value : `parseInt(bad1).getOrElse(defaultValue)`.

Comment: Thanks for replying Peter. However I have tried this but on running the queries against the spark table it throws errors. ' Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: None (of class scala.None$)
 at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Implicits$ImplicitSearch$$typedImplicit(Implicits.scala:458)'

Comment: I have two files. File 1 has null values. I applied your method to create the table from file one. Than I joined the two tables. So far good. Then I tries to register the output RDD as new table and that's when i get this error:-  `machineJoinedEvents.registerTempTable("machineJoinedEventsTable")
error: 
     
   uncaught exception during compilation: scala.MatchError
scala.MatchError: None (of class scala.None$)
That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  Shall I replay
your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.
[y/n]`

Comment: Like I said you need the handle `Option[Int]` and thus `None`. You could maybe filter out the rows with `None` before joining ? (I've never used Spark SQL).